Convert an array of unsigned short to JSON using the nlohmann library
I want to convert an array of unsigned short to JSON using the nlohmann library.
My variable type is a pointer to a null-terminated list of unsigned short. The typedef is this:
typedef unsigned short USHORT;
typedef USHORT * LPUSHORT;

I prepared this overload to conveniently process this type:
void to_json(nlohmann::json &resultJson, LPUSHORT lp)
{
    while (*lp != NULL)
    {
        nlohmann::json single = (*lp);
        resultJson["list"].push_back(single);
        lp++;
    }
}

But when doing this
resultJson["nids"] = (LPUSHORT) lp->nids;

I get the error:
no operator matches these operands
operand types are: nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::string, bool, int64_t, uint64_t, double, std::allocator, nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::adl_serializer, std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>, void> = LPUSHORT

I also tried it with other typedefs, which are structs of short, int, char*,... all this works. But not directly when converting LPUSHORT.

Please provide a [mre].

That library is designed to work with C++ not C. So do not use raw pointers to model arrays, but use std::vectorstd::uint8_t to store your data (https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/array_t/)

You have LPUSHORT lp and then lp->nids, unsigned short doesn't have member nids...

ADL works with classes, not with trivial types. so void to_json(nlohmann::json &resultJson, unsigned short* lp) won't be found in nlohman machinery.

@Jarod42 the -> operator has a higher precedence then a C-style cast, so (LPUSHORT) lp->nids will be interpreted as ((LPUSHORT)(lp->nids)), not as ((LPUSHORT)lp)->nids as you are thinking.

@RemyLebeau: the only lp shown by OP is of type LPUSHORT. Use another name to not confuse reader when type mismatch...

I am not sure it will work, but try this (C++20 and onwards):
#include <algorithm>
#include <span>

auto past_the_end_elem = std::find(std::cbegin((LPUSHORT)lp->nids), std::cend((LPUSHORT)lp->nids), nullptr);

resultJson["nids"] = std::span<USHORT>(std::cbegin((LPUSHORT)lp->nids, past_the_end_elem);


As mentioned also by others, the key is to convert the array to a e.g. vector first.

@mazi indeed. I would say the key is to make it a sequence (if supported via iteration abstraction). A pointer is not a sequence, but a pointer with a null-terminated value (this is basically what const char * is for strings) can be seen as a sequence. So the trick is to find the end of the sequence and convert your value to one such sequence. If std::span is supported, you avoid copying all data to a vector first, which is a potentially non-negligible cost.
